# Rails how create a fallback helper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to create a fallback helper for a object but on the page just shows the image broken link and the assets url. so, know how?

```
def display_image(pdata)  
    unless pdata.nil? 
      image_tag(pdata.image) 
    else
      image_tag("/assets/fallback/small_foto.png")
     end    
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it is an issue with how you're organising and referencing your assets. From [the Rails docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html):

> In regular views you can access images in the app/assets/images
>   directory like this:
>
> `<%= image_tag "rails.png" %>`

And if you want to use the custom `fallback` folder:

> Images can also be organized into subdirectories if required, and then
>   can be accessed by specifying the directory's name in the tag:
>
> `<%= image_tag "icons/rails.png" %>`

So, move your `fallback` folder into `assets/images` and reference it with:

`<%= image_tag "fallback/small_foto.png" %>`